# How to set a Datagridview at the centre of the form on form load event?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, load

I have a child form that loads within parent form on several events. It has datagridview which fetch some data from sql database. I am trying to set it at centre of the child form on form load event but i am unable to do so. Below is my code of child form with which i am trying it to set it to form centre.

```
 Private Sub SelectClinic_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    clNameDGV.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Calibri", 15, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)

    clNameDGV.RowHeadersVisible = False
    clNameDGV.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
    clNameDGV.ReadOnly = True
    clNameDGV.Location = New Point((Me.Width - clNameDGV.Width) / 2, (Me.Height - clNameDGV.Height) / 2)

    ChClinic()

End Sub


Private Sub ChClinic()
    conn = New SqlConnection("Server=(Local);Database=DrDB;user=Tarak;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    conn.Open()
    Dim comStr As String = "Select Count(*) from Clinicinfo"
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(comStr, conn)
    Dim i As Integer = comm.ExecuteScalar

    'CHECKING IF ANY CLINIC INFORMATION IS FOUND
    If i = 0 Then
        If MessageBox.Show("No clinic information found." + vbNewLine + "Will you like to create new clinic info right now ?", "No Clinic Info Found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = vbYes Then
            Dim nf As New ClinicDetails
            nf.TopMost = True
            nf.ShowDialog(Me)
        Else
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End If

    'LOADING CLINIC NAMES INTO DATAGRIDVIEW
    Dim comStr3 As String = "Select Count(*) from Login_Detail"
    Dim comm3 As New SqlCommand(comStr3, conn)
    Dim iCh As Integer = comm3.ExecuteScalar
    'MsgBox(iCh)
    Dim comStr2 As String
    If iCh = 0 Then
        comStr2 = "Select Clinic_Name from Clinicinfo"
    Else
        comStr2 = "Select DISTINCT Clinic_Name from Clinicinfo Where Clinic_Status = 'Active'"
    End If
    Dim comm2 As New SqlCommand(comStr2, conn)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    rd = comm2.ExecuteReader
    dt.Load(rd)
    'clNameDGV.Columns.Clear()
    clNameDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    clNameDGV.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    clNameDGV.DataSource = dt
    clNameDGV.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
    clNameDGV.Refresh()
    clNameDGV.Width = clNameDGV.Columns(0).Width
    clNameDGV.Location = New Point((Me.Width - clNameDGV.Width) / 2, (Me.Height - clNameDGV.Height) / 2)
    rd.Close()

    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

I have also created a button click event which deletes data from database and the sub ChClinic() runs in last, which cleans and refills the datagridview. After delete of the data and refill of the datagridview the datagridview sets to center of the child form.

Comment: Why don't you center your grid at design time and then set the Anchor property of the grid to all 4 sides of the child form?

Comment: May be [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?404224-RESOLVED-2005-Positioning-DatagridView-quot-Center-in-Form-quot-at-runtime) can help you.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the top left x,y location of the child form so it centers on the parent form, you need to include the parent.x value, which you are missing:

So this:

clNameDGV.Location = New Point((Me.Width - clNameDGV.Width) / 2, (Me.Height - clNameDGV.Height) / 2)

Should be this:

clNameDGV.Location = New Point(Me.Left + (Me.Width - clNameDGV.Width) / 2, Me.Top + (Me.Height - clNameDGV.Height) / 2)

That will get you the top left corner of a centered child...

Answer (score 0):

```
clNameDGV.Left = (Me.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (clNameDGV.Width / 2)
clNameDGV.Top= (Me.ClientSize.Height/ 2) - (clNameDGV.Height/ 2)
```

This will put the control exactly in the middle of the form